# Custom SKU pattern

Tags: magento2, sku

I want to create an custom SKU pattern that is somthing like this:

```
{attribute set id}{auto number}
```

and I want it to be at least 5 numbers long.

For example: 05004 where the **05** is for the attribute set and the **004** for the product. 
Is this possible with Magento (I don't think so)? 
Is there a good module for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, Module is not available for your requirements but you can do this by overwriting product save controller.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product
```

Overwrite this controller and change SKU as per your requirement before save.

you can also do it via observer with this event `catalog_product_save_commit_after`